# On Linux, how to determine the current TCP receive window size of a connection?

Tags: linux, tcp

For a given TCP connection, is there a CLI tool to determine the receiver's receive window size?  Also the sender's current receive size.  I could not find the information in the ss utility.

Comment: You can get the local receive and send buffer sizes, but not the remote ones, using `getsockopt()`. See `man 7 socket` for details.

Comment: modified question to ask for CLI tool. Thanks.

Comment: For the receiver or sender on the local machine `ss -m`, although the answer is in another coordinate system.  There is bytes in the queue and total memory used by the data structure representing the queue.  The kernel uses the latter.  https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3624151.